# Prevent jQuery to effect a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slideshow that works with javascript.

Now I implemented jQuery 1.8.3 in the head of my Website

Since then my Slideshow stopped working. But i need the jQuery for something else.

How can i disable the jQuery file for the ID "headerimages2"??

```
<div id="headerimages2">
  <div id="c8" class="csc-default">
    <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-left csc-textpic-above">
      <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap" style="width:487px; height:285px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The slideshow doesn't slide anymore, its just stuck at the first image.

Comment: are you having errors?

Comment: you have to include jquery migrate

Comment: check the console for any errors

Comment: @Jain no he dowsn't he uses 1.8.3

Comment: It would be unusual to "turn off jQuery" for part of the DOM.  You need to include enough code for someone else to be able to see and duplicate the problem.  Have you tried putting your slideshow into its own html/js files and loading it with an iframe?

Comment: The slideshow you are using may be using methods that were deprecated in version 1.8. Best way to do it would be either to change plugin (if you're using one), or port the code to work with newer versions of jQuery. If you're using a plugin for your slideshow which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jquery and javascript uses $ 
so,you can write your javascript code inside below function

```
$(function() {
//your javascript code here
});
```

and include your jquery library .

Answer (score 0):

> How can i disable the jQuery file for the ID "headerimages2"??

If you are using `jQuery` to apply some effects/actions by selecting some elements then you may exclude an element by using it's identifier with [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/), something like this:

```
$('someelements').not('#headerimages2').someMethod();
```

For example, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/H4DqB/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li id='headerimages2'>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('li').not('li#headerimages2').css('color', 'red');
```

So the action will not be applied on the element that has `headerimages2` as it's `id`.